# Get ISO date object from mongoDb using Java

Tags: java, isodate

I want to get Iso date object value from mongodb collection.

below is my mongodb Collections

```
  {
    "_id" : ObjectId("55c4657f036499106cf73fae"),
    "from" : "Administrator",
    "subject" : " Exception details :: InternalSession",
    "dateTs" : ISODate("2015-08-07T07:59:59.172Z") 
  }
```

i want to get dateTs column value i.e iSODate.

Below is my java code:

```
       while (requestsCursor.hasNext()) {

        DBObject dbObject = requestsCursor.next();
        JSONArray toArr = new JSONArray();

        String from = (String) (dbObject.containsField(FROM) ?          dbObject.get(FROM) : "-");

        ISO8601DateFormat dT = (ISO8601DateFormat) dbObject.get("dateTs");

        System.out.println("dateTs : "+dT);

    }
```

I am getting null value

please Suggest ..

Comment: Your code seams to be ok!  Perhaps something completely different happend. Perhaps you request the wrong collection. If you have two simmiliar collections and the name differs only little bit. Or you access another database. (Development and Test Database ????)